# Do you know when your undead is destroyed?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, undead

I am a necromancer. My undead are created using [animate dead](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/a/animate-dead/). As I can only control 4HD per CL, when I go over this limit I must release them, but I get to choose which ones are released. This implies some kind of awareness of the undead you control when you are the creator, whereas using the feat [command undead](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/general-feats/command-undead/) doesn't say how it works in that regard (either you lose control of the oldest, as you choose, or simply unable to use it when full).

So as you are able to choose which undead you release, would you recognize when one of them that you created and still control, is destroyed?

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like the sort of function that would be up to the GMs discretion. Their idea of how necromancy works in their setting would likely give you the answer you are searching for. Unless a spell has specific wording to guide you,  a lot of the nature of magical effects are generally up to the GMs ruling.

Comment: Can you support your answer by citing the relevant rules, or lack thereof? In particular, it would help to explicitly state (if true) that there are no rules covering whether a necromancer knows when their undead is destroyed or not - which is what would make it up to the GM's discretion. As written, your first sentence seems somewhat unsure.

Answer (score 1):

## Weak evidence against

Other skills which allow for control generally specify that there is a telepathic link between the caster and the subject (see dominate person). In all the instances of controlling undead (command undead, control undead) it says that you must give them verbal commands. This distinction, and the absence of text describing a link, is weak evidence against any sort of magical feedback between you and the controlled creature. However, since this exact issue is not addressed specifically, in the end it's up to your GM to determine what is reasonable.

Comment: Its not the giving of commands, its that bond that allows them to be controlled and given commands. Such a bond clearly exists because you are only able to control so many. Since you are able to choose which ones are released when making new ones there must be some sort of awareness about the bonds themselves. The feat is also permanent, but the spell is temporary and its established that casters do not know about ongoing spells unless the spell states it has feed back.